# Cors Exception in Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am having cors error in a `Node.js` application as follows:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/api/tutorials/1' from origin 'http://localhost:2240' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:8081' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
tutorial.component.js:91 Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:117:1)
xhr.js:210          PUT http://localhost:8081/api/tutorials/1 net::ERR_FAILED
```

The above are the messages from browser console. To avoid them, in the server-side with `Express.js` did the followings:

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8081"
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   //Website you wish to allow to connect
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

   //Request methods you wish to allow
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

   //Request headers you wish to allow
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

   //Pass to next layer of middleware
   next();
});
```

This actually occurs when I am trying to update an item in the database. So using axios, I am doing the following to do http request as follows:

```
import axios from "axios";
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8081/api",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  }
});
```

But still couldn't sort this out. Any way to resolve it in the proper way?

Comment: You don't need to set the headers yourself if you are using the `cors` middleware.

Comment: Could you specify a bit? Any workaround?

Comment: Remove the second middleware (`app.use` block), you don't need it.

Comment: Just change corsOptions.origin to "http://localhost:2240". Your web app is served from this address, so this is the origin of the request you need to allow.

Answer (score 1):

The CORS origin should be the domain of the site that is connecting to the server, not the server's address.

Change the port to `8080` or whatever port your site is running on:

```js
var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8080"
};
```

This allows the browser to ensure that it only connects to the server from sites that are trusted.

Comment: Ok, now having this - `PUT http://localhost:8081/api/tutorials/1 500 (Internal Server Error) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16:1)
    at settle (settle.js:17:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:1)`. In my case, origin is 2240 port.

Comment: Check the Node.js error logs, they should tell you what's wrong with the server.